# transform a pcl::pointcloud to binary image. c++

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library, binary-image

I'm trying to convert a planar section of a pcl::pointcloud into a binary image. I found a class called savePNGFile, but is not working well with my program.

Until now I did a ROI selector and a intensity filter to get the points I want.

```
void regionOfInterest(VPointCloud::Ptr cloud_in, double x1, double x2, 
double y1, double y2, double z)
{
  for (VPoint& point: cloud_in->points)
    if ((z > point.z) && (y1 > point.y) && (y2 < point.y) && (x1 > point.x) 
    &&(x2 < point.x))
      cloud_out->points.push_back(point);
}
```

(VPointCloud is the kind of pointcloud I need to work with my data)
I know that maybe the piece of code I show there is not relevant, but it can show you more or less the types I'm using.

Anybody knows how to export this pointcloud to binary image? After this step I will work with OpenCV.

Thank you

Comment: is pointcloud structured or unstructured

Comment: i assume this is dicom data? in which case it should be structured

Comment: What do you mean by binary image? whether or not a pixel on the projected camera has seen a point? or do you want a depth image with the filtered points? In any case, have you looked at [range image from point cloud](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/range_image_creation.php) or [point cloud to image](http://wiki.ros.org/pcl_ros/Tutorials/CloudToImage)? Moreover, you should check the [passthrough filter](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/passthrough.php)

Comment: Sorry about missing so much info, i'll start from the begining: First I get the pointcloud from a pcd file. I apply the filters and i get a smaller pointcloud with all the points in white where the depth is almost 0. Now I want to apply Deep Learning to get where in the image there are objects, but I need an image (binary image, array of 0 and 1) to pass it through the DL algorithm

Comment: Right I get what you are trying to do, my question is of structure though.  If you have it, u need to use it, and if you dont have it, you need to artificially create it in order to make an image

Comment: I don't know what you mean with structured... I'm using point clouds since a few days ago so I'm not very experimented yet...

Comment: can the be organized in an xyz array.  what generated the point cloud data?

Comment: Yes, it's organized

Answer (score 0):

This method should work for either organized or unorganized data. However you may need to rotate your input point cloud plane so that it is parallel to two of the orthogonal dimensions and you know what dimension you want to remove. stepSize1 and stepSize2 are parameters to set what size of the point cloud becomes a pixel in the new image. This calculates a grayscale image based on point density, but it could easily be modified to show depth or other information. A simple threshold can also be used to make the image binary.

```
cv::Mat makeImageFromPointCloud(pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud, std::string dimensionToRemove, float stepSize1, float stepSize2)
{
    pcl::PointXYZI cloudMin, cloudMax;
    pcl::getMinMax3D(*cloud, cloudMin, cloudMax);

    std::string dimen1, dimen2;
    float dimen1Max, dimen1Min, dimen2Min, dimen2Max;
    if (dimensionToRemove == "x")
    {
        dimen1 = "y";
        dimen2 = "z";
        dimen1Min = cloudMin.y;
        dimen1Max = cloudMax.y;
        dimen2Min = cloudMin.z;
        dimen2Max = cloudMax.z;
    }
    else if (dimensionToRemove == "y")
    {
        dimen1 = "x";
        dimen2 = "z";
        dimen1Min = cloudMin.x;
        dimen1Max = cloudMax.x;
        dimen2Min = cloudMin.z;
        dimen2Max = cloudMax.z;
    }
    else if (dimensionToRemove == "z")
    {
        dimen1 = "x";
        dimen2 = "y";
        dimen1Min = cloudMin.x;
        dimen1Max = cloudMax.x;
        dimen2Min = cloudMin.y;
        dimen2Max = cloudMax.y;
    }

    std::vector<std::vector<int>> pointCountGrid;
    int maxPoints = 0;

    std::vector<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr> grid;

    for (float i = dimen1Min; i < dimen1Max; i += stepSize1)
    {
        pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr slice = passThroughFilter1D(cloud, dimen1, i, i + stepSize1);
        grid.push_back(slice);

        std::vector<int> slicePointCount;

        for (float j = dimen2Min; j < dimen2Max; j += stepSize2)
        {
            pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr grid_cell = passThroughFilter1D(slice, dimen2, j, j + stepSize2);

            int gridSize = grid_cell->size();
            slicePointCount.push_back(gridSize);

            if (gridSize > maxPoints)
            {
                maxPoints = gridSize;
            }
        }
        pointCountGrid.push_back(slicePointCount);
    }

    cv::Mat mat(static_cast<int>(pointCountGrid.size()), static_cast<int>(pointCountGrid.at(0).size()), CV_8UC1);
    mat = cv::Scalar(0);

    for (int i = 0; i < mat.rows; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < mat.cols; ++j)
        {
            int pointCount = pointCountGrid.at(i).at(j);
            float percentOfMax = (pointCount + 0.0) / (maxPoints + 0.0);
            int intensity = percentOfMax * 255;

            mat.at<uchar>(i, j) = intensity;
        }
    }

    return mat;
}


pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr passThroughFilter1D(const pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud, const std::string field, const double low, const double high, const bool remove_inside)
{
    if (low > high)
    {
        std::cout << "Warning! Min is greater than max!\n";
    }

    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud_filtered(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>);
    pcl::PassThrough<pcl::PointXYZI> pass;

    pass.setInputCloud(cloud);
    pass.setFilterFieldName(field);
    pass.setFilterLimits(low, high);
    pass.setFilterLimitsNegative(remove_inside);
    pass.filter(*cloud_filtered);
    return cloud_filtered;
}
```

Comment: `pcl::passThroughFilter1D` does not exist! shouldn't that be `pcl::PassThrough` instead?

Comment: That is a custom method I created and is defined at the bottom of the code snippet